# Javascript window.opener.location.reload doesn't work on mobile pop-up

Tags: javascript, mobile, window.opener

I have a problem with the following javascript simple function :

I open a pop-up window from the parent page, with only a button in the popup calling the function :

```
    function closing() {
        try {
            window.opener.location.reload();
            alert("ok");
            window.close();

        } catch (e) { alert(e.description); }
    }
```

It works very simply: it reloads the parent page, alerts with "OK" message and then closes the pop-up. It works perfectly from computers :
http://www.carnet-de-vol.fr/V2/DGAC/open.aspx

But from mobiles (iPad, or Samsung Galaxy S4), the error message "undefined" appears in the try/catch test... it's caused by the window.opener.location.reload(); lign but I didn't find why... i've also tried window.opener.reload(), etc...

Do you have any idea ?

Regards.

J